# Tsunami Characteristics

Tags: tsunami

I got datasets about Tsunami events.

According to International Tsunami Information Center and Indian Ocean UNESCO Tsunami center, for an earthquake to cause Tsunami it should have a large magnitude (> 6.5) and shallow focal depth ( < 100 km ).

But there are entries in NOAA tsunami dataset with focal depth of 260 km and a magnitude of 6.8 occurred at sea with the epicenter located at 21.1 km from the nearest coast. There are also entries with magnitude range of 4-5 causing tsunamis.

Are there some other characteristics of earthquake that may cause tsunami?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rupture velocity of earthquakes is another factor that determines the magnitude of a tsunami.  The term [tsunami earthquakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsunami_earthquake) was coined by Hiroo Kanamori in 1972 to describe when an earthquake having a slower rupture velocity (~1km/sec), compared to a more normal velocity (2.5-3.5 km/sec) of a typical earthquake, causes a tsunami greater in magnitude than expected.

[This paper](http://www.eri.u-tokyo.ac.jp/people/seno/Papers/2001GL013149.pdf) investigates the effect of a horizontal movement of sediments due to an 1896 earthquake that may have created a tsunami earthquake.

Comment: Is there any relatioship between magnitude, focal depth and rupture velocity  of an earthquake so that we can compute rupture velocity by magnitude and focal depth.

Comment: I'm not finding any definitive equation relating these parameters, but [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2007JB005434/full?scrollTo=footer-citing) from the Journal of Geophysical Research presents ways of estimating rupture velocity of large deep focus earthquakes.  Maybe there is something within this that will help.